# Android Defer to Camera

Tags: android, camera

Is there a way, from within my own application, to open up the default camera app and use *that* to get a picture/video? I keep trying to look it up but I only ever find instructions on cloning the camera app myself (usually with very bad instructions). I know this can be done with the iPhone, I would be surprised if it wasn't possible with Android.

Answer (score 3):

To get the camera to take a picture and then get the image that it just took use the following

```
// Call to take the picture using the default camera
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"), PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

// After the camera intent finished returns the uri of the image taken
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
                // set the imageview image via uri 
                _previewImage.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the snippet. It is exactly what I was looking for. No need to implement the camera functionality again while there is a perfect implementation...

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code where he starts the Camera intent and gets the image taken:

http://www.androidph.com/2008/11/camera-capture.html

(Warning, it's about a year old, so it will need a little updating).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can. That's one of the ideas behind Android's intents.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).