# where is android.camera.NEW_PICTURE defined?

Tags: android, camera

I used `com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE` to check whether an image is captured or not.

```
(receiver android:name="NewPhotoReceiver")
    (intent-filter)

            (action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE"/)

            (data android:mimeType="image/*"/)

    (/intent-filter)
(/receiver)
```

But `com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE` is not discussed any where in android developers site.

Answer (score 9):

In API 14 (ICS) and above, you can use the action "**android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE**", which is referenced here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE

So I guess specifying both of them together should cover both past & future usage:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
    <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And the only question left is whether any OEM doen't broadcast "com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" on a pre-ICS Android...

Comment: I was wondering why this wasn't working for my. After installing a new camera app to the emulator I saw that I forgot to put the <receiver> and <intend-filter> tags around this excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [the source of the Camera app](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/camera/Camera.java;hb=HEAD):

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE", mLastContentUri));
```

So the *data* property of the intent contains the image URI. You can get the physical path by the methods discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath/2790688#2790688).

If you want to take a picture from your application, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657640/android-defer-to-camera).

Answer (score 0):

It's not official - there can be a lot of different implementations to the camera app (by phone manufacturers and even market apps), so you should only use documented intent actions.

'com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE' is NOT documented and not official. I don't know what is.

Answer (score 0):

one problem that also occurs while using both actions with receivers

android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" 
android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE"

is duplicate call of onReceived() method on some devices (tested on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini specifically) so you should prefer using only documented 
android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE"

Answer (score 0):

As the broadcast intent action itself implies "`com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE`" is not generated within the android API framework, thus it shall not be listed in the android API documentation and of course it is not existing in any android API source `.java` file.

But it is generated by an app (`com.android.camera`) and only the app manufacturer and designers can list (in their app documentation or in the source code if open) which broadcast intent their app is sending.