# Broadcast Receiver New picture capture in android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-camera2

Can anybody help me please? My question is that how to to display popup message on camera image capture using broadcast receiver.

I have register Receiver but it is not working.

Receiver class:

```
public class CameraReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("INFO", "Enter BroadcastReceiver");



        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(),
                null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "New Photo is Saved as : " + image_path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.example.abdullahnawaz.mycamera.CameraReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052464/1568530

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 7.0, please use [JobInfo.Builder.addTriggerContentUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)).

For older devices, you can listen to the [ACTION_NEW_PICTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) or [ACTION_NEW_VIDEO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#ACTION_NEW_VIDEO) broadcast. These broadcasts are no long sent on 7.0 and above.